# returning an abstract class from a function

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Is it possible to return an abstract class(class itself or a reference, doesn't matter) from a function?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can return an abstract class pointer - assuming `B` is a concrete class derived from abstract class `A`:

```
A * f() {
    return new B;
}
```

or a reference:

```
A & f() {
    static B b;
    return b;
}
```

or a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> f() {
    return std::make_unique<B>(...);
}
```

Comment: i want to use the abstract class itself (or its reference), to use it as a generic form for other classes which are derived from that abstract class

Comment: @cemregoksu That's the only purpose for having an abstract class. Both the functions above illustrate how you would do this with respect to function return values.

Comment: And if `B` is declared somewhere else, make sure it's a public subclass of `A`, e.g. `class B : public A` instead of `class B: A`. Or else you may get very misleading error messages.

Answer (score 20):

You can *declare* the return type to be a reference or pointer to the abstract class, so that it can be assigned to references or pointers to the abstract class and used based on its interface.

However, *you cannot return an actual instance of the actual abstract class* because by definition you cannot instantiate it. You could, however, return instances of concrete subtypes which is good enough because by the [principle of substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), you should always be able to use a subtype instead of a supertype.

Answer (score 5):

No, but a function could have a return type of a pointer (or a reference) to an abstract class. It would then return instances of a class that is derived from the abstract class.

Comment: You mean "return type of *a reference to* an abstract class".

Comment: I couldnt understand what you mean. can you give a little example?

Comment: IBM is not a good source - that site has some truly crappy information on it.

Comment: @incrediman, and I can return references to (an object of) a class.

Comment: @sbi: The OP didn't say that the function would be abstract. He said that the function's return type would be an abstract class. Like this: `Foo f(){...}` where Foo is an abstract class. Which is perfectly valid. Edit: sbi deleted his comment.

Comment: @incrediman: `abstract f()` is not valid in C++ if `abstract` is an abstract class.

Comment: @sbi: I'm not sure I understand.  If I have an abstract base class called Shape and a concrete child named Circle, why can't I define foo() to return a Shape reference or pointer?

Comment: @sbi Yes - the answer has been edited repeatedly within the initial grace period so the edits don't show up.

Comment: @Steven Sudit, you can, but it has to be a reference or a pointer. Read sbi's comment again.

Comment: @sbi: Turns out you're right :)

Can you explain why that is? Edit: Actually it's because you cannot instantiate an instance of the class, so it has to be a pointer.

Comment: @avakar: Oh, ok.  Yes, you can't return a copy of the ABC, just a reference (or pointer) to it.  That's because no ABC can be instantiated, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated and thus not returned.

Comment: What about the reference?

I know that it is not possible to pass an abstract class as a parameter to a function, but i could pass the reference of the abstract class.

Comment: Only if the references actually refers to an instance of a child class.

Comment: well, what about that scenario?

class A{
virtual void f()=0;
};

void fonk(A &a){}
works.
so is it possible to form the function to return a reference of the class again?

Answer (score 1):

The *Factory* design pattern is an example of returning a pointer to an abstract class object:

```
class Base
{ ; }

class One : public Base
{ ; }

class Two : public Base
{ ; }

Base * Factory(unsigned int number)
{
  Base * p_item(NULL);
  switch (number)
  {
    case 1:
      p_item = new One;
      break;
    case 2:
      p_item = new Two;
      break;
    default:
      p_item = NULL;
      break;
  }
  return p_item;
}
```

An actual abstract base class object can never be returned since there can never be an *instance* of an abstract base class.  Pointers and references to an abstract base type can be returned as in the above example.

Pointers and references to an abstract base class returned from a function or method actually refer to a descendant of the abstract base type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return abstract class itself in the funtion return, but abstract class point and abstract class reference are both OK.

The only thing you need to worry is if you return by point, will the caller own the object and release, if you return by reference, be careful to return funtion's local variable, it compiles fine but it will crash. The function local variable will be released after the function call, like the following code, it will crash at line "a.print();". Hopefully it make sense.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    
    public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "print";
    }
    
    A& GetA() {
        
        B b;
        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    
    B b;
    A &a = b.GetA();
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment to the lines with B b; return b; The object b will be stored on stack and not on heap! Here we have the typical memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from @stakx, I prefer the smart pointer approach as the default:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> f() {
    return std::make_unique<B>(...);
}
```

While the other two approaches are viable (returning a raw pointer or returning a reference), this has the big advantage of simplifying memory management in the calling code.

Answer (score -6):

I know I'm little late but I hope this will help someone...

Being a newbie in C++ programming, I've also been stuck for a while on that problem. I wanted to create a factory method that returns an reference to an abstract object. My first solution using pointers worked well but I wanted to stay in a more "C++ manner". Here is the code snippet I wrote to demonstrate it:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Abstract{
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class FirstFoo: public Abstract{
  void foo()
  {
    cout << "Let's go to the foo bar!" << endl;
  }
};

class SecondFoo: public Abstract{
  void foo()
  {
    cout << "I prefer the foo beer !" << endl;
  }
};

Abstract& factoryMethod(){
  static int what = 0;

  if(what++ % 2 == 0)
    return *(new FirstFoo());
  else
    return *(new SecondFoo());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int howMany = 10;
  int i = 0;

  while(i++ < howMany)
  {
    Abstract& abs = factoryMethod();
    abs.foo();
    delete &abs;
  }
}
```

Open to any critism !

Comment: `factoryMethod` leaks memory every time you call it. The result is allocated on the heap, but it's never deleted. (The caller can't delete it because they get a reference instead of a pointer.)

Comment: I agree with the memory leak issue, but I just learnt how to import specific symbols from a namespace using `using`, I only knew about `using namespace` so far! Thanks for that @morandg!

Comment: Seeing this answer few years later I have to say that **this is an horrible design don't do it**! With CPP I guess there is no other choice than returning a pointer to the abstract class and make sure that someone is responsible for deleting the object. Using shared/smart pointers seems to be a viable solution as well.