# C++: Returning abstract type as an interface

Tags: c++, subclassing

I'm trying to achieve something illustrated with this piece of code, but I can't get it to work. I can't return an `Animal`, and I really don't think returning an `Animal*` would be a good solution, because I'd have to `new` and `delete` manually.

**EDIT**: I updated the question with a more specific code snippet, demonstrating why returning `Animal*` isn't a really good idea.

As you can see from the snippet, I basically want to use an `Animal` as
an interface for a bunch of data, and that data may be part of an array
or it may be a more conventional object.

**EDIT 2**: Working example: http://ideone.com/4qp3qT

Remaining problems:

- duplicate code (`FeedAnimals()`)
- performance?
- having to `delete` manually (for the cats)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


class Animal {
    virtual void eat() = 0;
};

// Dog is more high-level
class Dog: public Animal {
    char attr1;
    char attr2;

    Dog(_attr1, _attr2):
        attr1(_attr1),
        attr2(_attr2)
        {}

    Dog():
        attr1('d'),
        attr2('g')
        {}

    void eat() {
        cout << "Dog ate food (" << attr1 << attr2 << ").\n";
    }

    void barf() {
        cout << "Whaf";
    }
};

// Cat is more low-level
class Cat: public Animal {
    // A cat can basically only exist in a cage
    // and it's attributes are defined by it's location
    // in the Cage's underlying array. A Cat should also
    // have to 2 attributes (both char), so this would
    // be kind of true:
    //   sizeof(Cat) == 2

    char* ptr;

    // I will only use a Cat in a context of arrays, so
    // no need to care about memory management here.
    Cat(char* _ptr):
        ptr(_ptr)
        {}

    void eat() {
        cout << "Cat ate food (" << *ptr << *(ptr+1) << ").\n";
    }

    void meow() {
        cout << "Meow.";
    }
};


class Cage {
    virtual Animal GetRandomAnimal() = 0;
};

// DogCage uses a nice (more high level) vector
class DogCage {
    vector<Dog> dogs;

    DogCage():
        dogs(5)
        {}

    Animal GetRandomAnimal() {
        // ?
    }
}

// CatCage uses a more low level pointer together with
// malloc etc.
class CatCage {
    char* cats;

    CatCage():
        cats((char*) malloc(4*2)) // room for 4 cats
        {}

    ~CatCage() {
        free(cats);
    }

    Animal GetRandomAnimal() {
        // ...

        // This is why it's difficult to return a pointer
        // to an Animal. I basically want to use a Cat as
        // a simple interface to a part of an array.
        // If I use pointers etc, that seems like it would
        // hit performance.
        return Cat(cats+(random*2))
    }
}

void FeedAnimals(Animal& a) {
    a.eat();
}

int main() {
    Cage cage; // ?
    string s;

    cout << "Cats or dogs?";
    cin >> s;
    if (s=="Cats") {
        cage = CatCage(); // ?
    } else {
        cage = DogCage(); // ?
    }

    // fill cage with animals (either cats or dogs)

    FeedAnimals(cage.GetRandomAnimal());
}
```

Comment: You can't return by value since the type is abstract, you don't want to do this anyway since you'll have problems with object slicing. You need to return by pointer or by reference.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861270/returning-an-abstract-class-from-a-function) question and answer

Comment: "Dogs and cats living together, mass hysteria!"

Comment: "If I use pointers etc, that seems like it would hit performance."  Get something working first.  Implement it in the most logical way.  Then, if you have performance issues, think about optimizing it.

Comment: @JacobRobbins I updated the question with link to a working example. Now I am stuck.

Comment: @evertheylen Others have already given you what you need.  What you're trying to do (use `Animal` as a base class for `Cat` & `Dog` which both have their own implementations for `eat`...well, that's polymorphism.  You need pointers.  Don't fear them, just make sure you know who owns each one.  Smart pointers make it easier.

Comment: @JacobRobbins I don't fear pointers, but because a `Cat` is only defined by another pointer, It would be a pointer to a pointer. For performance matters, I'd like C++ to just parse these abstractions so using a Cat will simply use the underlying chars in the manually allocated block of memory.
If I use pointers for an `Animal`, that would (AFAIK) result in unnecessary computation.

In this way, the problem reduces to why I can't return a reference to a locally defined `Cat` variable in the function `GetRandomAnimal()`.

Comment: You could return an `Animal const&` to the (temporary) `Cat(...)`, I think.  Have you tried it?  Of course, you will only be able to call `const` methods on the `const&` that you get.  If you want to modify the `Animal` reference, you'll need a pointer.  If `CatCage` was a *container* of `Cat` objects, you could return a reference to the `Cat` objects.  For some reason, you aren't doing that here, though.

Comment: @JacobRobbins exactly. And indeed, I tried to have Cats implicitly saved inside an array and create a Cat 'on the fly', but that didn't work. Returning references to locally defined objects didn't seem to work either.

Comment: It didn't seem to work because it *cannot* work.  If you return a reference to a function-local object, what does the reference refer to when the object goes out of scope?  That's why you can't do it.  As I mentioned above, returning a `const&` to a **temporary** object (as in `return Cat(...);`) is a special case.  In that special case, the compiler allows it (the `const&` "extends the life of" the temporary object).  If you did `Cat mittens(...); return mittens;`, then mittens is a local, so it must be dtor'd when the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is that you're arbitrarily trying to avoid using the tools (pointer, reference, or smart pointer) available for the job.

I'm guessing, this is because you are familiar with some other language that seems to permit this.   The thing is, languages which do such things do it by blending concepts of object, reference, and pointer in ways that C++ does not.

It is not possible in C++ to return an abstract class by value.  Period. Returning a class by value means it is necessary to instantiate it and an abstract class is one that cannot be instantiated.

If your function returns a raw reference or pointer, it is necessary that the objects exist when the caller uses them, and that the objects are released (cease to exist) when no longer needed.    Either that means your function accepts responsibility for managing object lifetime (e.g. the object is an element of an array) or that the caller is (e.g. function dynamically creates object, caller releases it when done).

Returning a smart pointer means returning an object that manages lifetime of the contained object.   The function creates the object, hands it to a smart pointer, and the smart pointer is returned to the caller.   When the smart pointer no longer exists (e.g. caller returns so it passes out of scope), the object is released.

Comment: I just want to be able to write functions that can take a `Cage` as argument, and have the `Cage` contain `Animal`s (because the function doesn't know about the exact type of the cage) on which I can call methods. `Cat` in particular is low-level, it is basically a way to handle a part of an array.
I could replace the `Cat` with a bunch of functions to keep them efficient, but that seems against the OOP principles C++ is built on.

Comment: If that's the case, you need not return an Animal (or Cat) at all, as it represents implementation details within the Cage object, and your functions don't need access to them in any way.   Trying to avoid returning references/pointers in order to impose some arbitrary notion of "OOP purity" on that is also just pointless.

Comment: I eventually solved it by some more C++ unsafe data magic. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: For future readers, what I was trying to achieve is not possible, and you should use pointers, as this answers clearly states (as such, I've marked this one as the answer).

Comment: I didn't state that one should use pointers.  I said that, for what you described, it is silly to arbitrarily avoid using available tools that meet the purpose.    I certainly did not suggest using any "C++ unsafe data magic" as an alternative.   Your characterising things that way actually reveals your need to better understand features of C++ so you select and use them appropriately.

Comment: I now see that the things I like to do would require some pointer arithmetic and malloc's anyway (which I sometimes call unsafe data magic :) ), whatever way you look at it (I'm limited by some library). Solving this problem has helped me understand C++ better now, I think I'm ok now :) .

Answer (score 1):

Pointers don't have to point to dynamic objects, and only need `delete` if they do (in which case consider a smart pointer).

In the case of the animals, you can just return a reference or pointer to one of the animals in the cage.

```
Animal & GetRandomAnimal() {
    return cats[GetRandomIndex()];
}
```

For the cage itself, dynamic allocation is the easiest way to make it polymorphic; but you should use a smart pointer to avoid faffing around with `delete` and debugging memory leaks.

```
std::unique_ptr<Cage> cage;

if (s=="Cats") {
    cage.reset(new CatCage); // C++14: cage = std::make_unique<CatCage>();
} else {
    cage.reset(new DogCage); // C++14: cage = std::make_unique<DogCage>();
}
```

If you're stuck in the past, replace `unique_ptr` with `auto_ptr`, `boost::scoped_ptr`, or a hand-rolled equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an `Animal` because you can't create an `Animal` (it's an abstract type). You need something that any Animal (`Cat`, `Dog`, etc.) can hide behind: a pointer or a reference. If you create all your animals beforehand, you could return a (preferably const) reference:

```
Cat cat;
Dog dog;

Animal const& GetRandomAnimal()
{
    if (rand() == 42) {
        return cat;
    }
    else {
       return dog;
    }
}
```

However, if you want to return an animal object (instance) which didn't exist before, your only option is to create on the heap and return a pointer. Returning a pointer has the problem that it's unclear who is responsible for deleting the object. With C++11, your best bet is to return a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> GetRandomAnimal()
{
    if (rand() == 42) {
        return std::make_unique<Cat>(/*args to the cat constructor*/);
    }
    else {
        return std::make_unique<Dog>(/*args to the dog constructor*/);
    }
}
```

or use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared`.
(alas, std::make_unique is C++14)

Comment: I changed the code snippet to be more specific, demonstrating why a pointer (or smart pointer for that matter) is far from perfect in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't a WhiteMouse be returned when rand() == 42?