# C++ - Override virtual function and polymorphism

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, covariance

I think I don't get something a very basic concept on virtual behavior.
I want to create the following hierarchy:

```cpp
    class Parser{

       virtual Parsable parse() = 0;
    }

    class SpecialParser : public Parser{

       SpecialParsable parse() override; // implemented

    }
```

Where clearly `SpecialParsable` class inherits from `Parsable`.

This returns me an error because of the different signature. `(SpecialParser::parse() returns SpecialParsable instead of Parsable)`.

Now, Parsable is clearly an abstract class and I don't want to make it possible to be instantiated. I don't understand why shouldn't be possible to do that since SpecialParsable is only a specific implementation of a Parsable.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: They need to return the same type.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861270/returning-an-abstract-class-from-a-function) for how to return the object. And for the different return types, `SpecialParsable` must inherit from `Parseable`, but I guess this is the case?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic polymorphism in C++ relies on indirection. If you return a pointer (or a reference), your example will compile and behave as expected. This is called a "covariant return type":

```
class Parser {
   virtual Parsable* parse() = 0;
};

class SpecialParser : public Parser {
   SpecialParsable* parse() override; // implemented
};
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BNGlat)

Comment: Is there viable reason to do this? I mean if you call `parse()` from base class pointer/reference, then you don't know "real" return type anyway. And if you call it directly from derived class then why doing it virtual? Or if it is virtual, for some other reason, then adding `static_cast` on returned pointer should be much simpler way...

Comment: @sklott: covariance allows to use most specialized class once you know the class. From `Parser`, you only got `Parsable`, but from `SpecialParser` you might have access to additional functionality from `SpecialParsable`, or limit yourself to `Parsable` interface.