# Can we declare a abstract method to return subclass objects in abstract superclass without new instantiation?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to build a class (eg. VectorSpace) which will have certain methods abstractly present in the class. 
I have recently moved from Java to c++ and I'm finding problems in trying to rephrase the general abstract method declaration in java

The situation is that c++ does not allow declaration such as:
AbstractClass methodName(...) = 0; 
Java, on the other hand allows the return type to be an abstract class.
This is not allowed in c++ and compilation results in error saying that abstract class cannot act as return type for method. 
I have gone through this page: [returning an abstract class from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861270/returning-an-abstract-class-from-a-function) . 
So I did the following in c++:

```
//Fields are any classes which +,* defined on them
  template<class F> class VectorSpace
  {
    virtual VectorSpace<F>* operator+(const VectorSpace<F>& el) const =0;
    virtual VectorSpace<F>* operator-() const =0;
    virtual VectorSpace<F>* operator*(const F& el) const =0;
    ....
  };
  class Vector : public VectorSpace<double>
  {
      ....
      Vector* operator+(const VectorSpace<double>& el) const {return new Vector(....);}
  }
```

However, the problem with this will be that I'll be using "new" to instantiate an object for any class that is a subclass of VectorSpace (like Vector) whenever any operators (eg +,-) are applied, which will have to be manually deleted.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You could return a reference, but the `VectorSpace<F>` has to live somewhere; if you return a reference to a temporary object (and your use of `operator +` suggests you'd be returning a temporary), you'll have other problems.

Comment: Why do you call it VectorSpace? It literally means that objects of classes derived from VectorSpace<double> would be vector spaces, not vectors.

Comment: This looks like you are forcing a Java design to C++.  Without knowing the problem you want to solve, it is always difficult to be sure, but in C++ we'd probably template the places where VectorSpace is used instead of making VectorSpace an abstract class.

Comment: Do operators really need to be virtual or they actually will have the same implementation? There are two diferrent solutions in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another class, say `VectorWrapper`, that wraps a pointer to abstract class, e.g. through a `std::unique_ptr<VectorSpace<double> >`. In this class you can overload `operator+` to redirect the call to the implementation, and then return a new locally constructed wrapper. Manual deletion is avoided by `std::unique_ptr` facility, and you have overloaded operators that return by value - so they're easy to use. Note that operators `new` and `delete` are still called under the hood and incapsulated by VectorWrapper .

```
class VectorWrapper 
{
    VectorWrapper(std::unique_ptr<VectorSpace<double> > ptr)
        : m_impl(std::move(ptr))
    {}
    VectorWrapper operator+(const VectorWrapper& other)
    {
         return VectorWrapper(*m_impl + *other.m_impl);
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<VectorSpace<double> > m_impl;
};
```

It's closely related to type erasure C++ idiom.

Edit: also you'll need to implement copy constructor and assignment to call `std::make_unique` etc.. Or if Vectors are immutable - just as mathematical objects are - you may consider using `std::shared_ptr`, but it may be even slower depending on how often `VectorWrapper` is copied in your code.